# using Either to parse failure and success

Tags: scala, spray-json

I'm trying to merge a Github pull request using spray. [Github's API](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#merge-a-pull-request-merge-button) will return different values depending on whether it succeeds or fails.

How do I parse that into an `Either`?

Using the following imports:

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import spray.client.pipelining._
import spray.json._
import scala.concurrent.Future
```

Their protocol looks like this:

```
object GithubWebProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  case class MergeSuccess(message:String, merged:Boolean, sha:String)
  case class MergeFailure(message:String, documentation_url:String)
  implicit val mergeSuccessFormat = jsonFormat3(MergeSuccess)
  implicit val mergeFailureFormat = jsonFormat2(MergeFailure)
}
```

Then if I have an app that looks like this:

```
object GithubWebAPITester extends App {
  implicit val system = ActorSystem()
  import system.dispatcher
  import GithubWebProtocol._

  val api = "https://api.github.com/v3"

  case class PullRequest(org:String, proj:String, pr:Int)

  val mergePullRequest:PullRequest => Future[Either[MergeFailure, MergeSuccess]] = pr => {
    val req = Post(s"$api/repos/${pr.org}/${pr.proj}/pulls/${pr.pr}/merge")
    val pipeline = addHeader("Authorization", s"token ${sys.env("GITHUB_TOKEN")}") ~>
      sendReceive ~>
      unmarshal[Either[MergeFailure, MergeSuccess]]
    pipeline(req)
  }

  mergePullRequest(PullRequest("dvmlls", "slakka-bot", 15)).onComplete {
    case a:Any =>
      println(a)
      system.terminate()
      sys.exit()
  }
}
```

I get the following compile error:

```
[error] ./src/main/scala/GithubWebAPI.scala:27: could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type spray.httpx.unmarshalling.FromResponseUnmarshaller[Either[GithubWebProtocol.MergeFailure,GithubWebProtocol.MergeSuccess]]
[error]       unmarshal[Either[MergeFailure, MergeSuccess]]
[error]                ^
```

What's the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this, there were two problems:

1. IntelliJ was incorrectly suggesting that I remove the following line, which is required:

`import spray.httpx.SprayJsonSupport._`

2. Need to add a `rootEitherFormat` as per this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25417819/908042

The combination of those two were killin' me.

Working code here: https://github.com/dvmlls/slakka-bot/commit/b7aacdf506c36eb5244d6f1bdd1a707c47aaf5c2